# Getting the max occurences of each individual number from a HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>>

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I've been dealing with an exercise, in which I have to find a solution for the following problem: I have a

```
HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>>
```

and I have to get a List containing each of the elements of all of the lists in the HashMap with the maximum number of occurrences in any of the lists. So let's suppose my HashMap has got the following entries:

```
25, [30,30,2]

7, [2, 2, 2]

8, [8, 30]
```

In this case, I should somehow get a List with the following elements: [2, 2, 2, 8, 30, 30], because the maximum occurrences of each of the numbers are:

- in the case of 2 it's 3 (in the value 7)
- in the case of 8 it's 1 (in the value 8)
- in the case of 30 it's 2 (in the value 25)

I am trying to use streams to do so, and I've written the following code:

```
map.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This gets the individual lists, but what I need is to get one list, containing all the elements in any of the lists, with the maximum number of times it was mentioned. The order of the elements does not matter at all.

Please ask me if you need some clarification.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: I doubt this can be done in a single pass.  Do you have to use a Stream?  It seems like loops would make the task easier.

Comment: No, it's not a must; I just wanted to pracitce streams and I somehow felt that it would have to be solvable using them.

Comment: To get the map’s values, you don’t need to convert a stream of entries;  just use [values()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#values%28%29).

Comment: I guess you can use a Stream with a custom collector, if only to practice how to use those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can it like this:

```
static List<Integer> maxOccurrence(Map<Integer, List<Integer>> input) {
    return input.values().stream()
        .flatMap(list -> list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting())).entrySet().stream())
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.naturalOrder()))))
        .entrySet().stream().sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
        .flatMap(e -> LongStream.range(0, e.getValue().get()).mapToObj(x -> e.getKey()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

*Test*

```
System.out.println(maxOccurrence(Map.of(
        25, List.of(30, 30, 2),
        7, List.of(2, 2, 2),
        8, List.of(8, 30))));
```

*Output*

```
[2, 2, 2, 8, 30, 30]
```

*Explained*

1. Stream the values, i.e. the lists:

   ```
   input.values().stream()
   ```

   ```
   [8, 30]
   [2, 2, 2]
   [30, 30, 2]
   ```
2. Count the occurrences of each value in each list:

   ```
   .flatMap(list -> list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting())).entrySet().stream())
   ```

   ```
   8=1
   30=1
   2=3
   30=2
   2=1
   ```
3. For each number, pick the highest occurrence:

   ```
   .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.naturalOrder()))))
   ```

   ```
   {8=1, 2=3, 30=2}
   ```
4. Stream that sorted by number (key):

   ```
   .entrySet().stream().sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
   ```

   ```
   2=3
   8=1
   30=2
   ```
5. Repeat each number by the occurrence:

   ```
   .flatMap(e -> LongStream.range(0, e.getValue().get()).mapToObj(x -> e.getKey()))
   ```

   ```
   2
   2
   2
   8
   30
   30
   ```
6. Build a list with the result:

   ```
   .collect(Collectors.toList())
   ```

   ```
   [2, 2, 2, 8, 30, 30]
   ```

Comment: Instead of `.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.naturalOrder()))))`, you can use the simpler `.collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, Long::max))`, which also eliminates the need to call `get()` (on an `Optional`) later-on. And when you use `.collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, Long::max, TreeMap::new))`, you don’t need the subsequent `.sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())` step.

Comment: @Holger True. Since the other 2 answers shows it that way, I'll leave it as-is. and sure, I could also have used the version of `groupingBy` that takes a map supplier, same as `toMap` has such an overload, but sorting at the end is easy and faster, and the other 2 answers didn't do that, so I think explicitly sorting the keys is better, to highlight that ordering is needed.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quick solution using streams :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(25, Arrays.asList(30, 30, 2));
    map.put(7, Arrays.asList(2, 2, 2));
    map.put(8, Arrays.asList(8, 30));

    List<Integer> result = map.values().stream() // Stream<List<Integer>>
            .map(e -> e.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p -> p, Collectors.counting()))) // Stream<Map<Integer,Long>>
            .flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream()) // Stream<Entry<Integer,Long>>
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, Long::max)) // Map<Integer,Long>
            .entrySet().stream() // Stream<Entry<Integer,Long>>
            .flatMap(e -> repeatElement(e.getKey(), e.getValue())) // Stream<Integer>
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println(result);
}

private static Stream<Integer> repeatElement(Integer key, Long value) {
    return Stream.generate(() -> key)
            .limit(value);
}
```

**Output**

```
[2, 2, 2, 8, 30, 30]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just use this:

```
List<Integer> result = map.values().stream()
        .flatMap(list -> list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> i, Collectors.summingInt(i -> 1))).entrySet().stream())
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, Integer::max)).entrySet().stream()
        .flatMap(e -> Collections.nCopies(e.getValue(), e.getKey()).stream())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

First you use `flatMap()` with `groupingBy()` to get the counts of the numbers. Then you collect all to make the numbers (`Entry.getKey()`) distinct using the max of the occurrences (`Entry.getValue()`). Finally you can use `Collections.nCopies()` to `flatMap()` a list with the size of your maximum occurrences.

The result will be:

```
[2, 2, 2, 8, 30, 30]
```